# Как разделить массив байт по несколько бит?

Tags: c#, массивы, битовые-операции

Есть файл, в котором некоторые данные "запакованы" равномерным кодированием (до 8 бит включительно на 1 значение, при этом число бит на значение известно). Нужен какой-нибудь универсальный алгоритм, который будет создавать массив (ну или список) байт, где каждое значение будет лежать в отдельной ячейке. 
Как пример работы программы:
Метод с такой сигнатурой (условно):

```
/// source - исходный массив бит, elementSize - длина одного элемента в битах, 
/// elementsNumber - лимит на длину конечного массива
byte[] Decompress(byte[] source, int elementSize, int elementsNumber)
```

Есть условный массив, который нужно распаковать:
`{0b00101010, 0b01010101, 0b11100010, 0b00010000}` (в принципе, содержимое не имеет значения.)
Размер элемента - например, 3 
Ну и лимита указывать не буду
Соответственно, метод должен как-то разделить исходный массив не по 8, а по 3 бита, чтобы получиось что-то такое на выходе:
`{0b001, 0b010, 0b100, 0b101, 0b010, 0b111, 0b100, 0b010, 0, 0b100}`

Также хотелось бы узнать насчёт того, есть ли какие-нибудь готовые более удобные и эффективные с точки зрения степени сжатия/скорости выполнения алгоритмы сжатия данных, чем равномерное кодирование?

UPD: Что я начал делать, но у меня не получилось

```
for (int i = 0; i < source.Length; i++)
{
       
   buffer = source[i];
   int shift = 8 - elementSize;
   if (j < 8)
   {
      //Видимо тут нужно как-то добавить значение из буфера, если в буфере что-то осталось
   }
   for (j = 0; shift - j > 0; j += elementSize)
   {
      ret.Add(buffer >> (shift - j));//Если я правильно понимаю, то вот так можно взять нужное число бит. 
//Действия снизу должны их убрать из этого байта:
      buffer <<= shift - j;
      buffer >>= shift - j;
   }
}
```

Comment: Пожалуйста, уточните вашу конкретную проблему или приведите более подробную информацию о том, что именно вам нужно. В текущем виде сложно понять, что именно вы спрашиваете.

Comment: Познакомьтесь с `BitArray`.

Comment: `лимит на длину конечного массива` а это вообще зачем? Кстати, а сами вы пытались решить задачу? Что именно не получается? Покажите код.

Comment: @aepot, ну лимит необязательно вводить, просто если, например, будет 4 значения по 3 бита, то останется 4 бит свободно в последнем байте, и программа может считать одно лишнее значение. Я пытался сделать что-то примерно такое: (обновил вопрос). Касательно `BitArray` посмотрю

Comment: Спасибо большое, попытаюсь воспользоваться BitArray для этой задачи